# DHCP Relay behind two router

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dhcp-server

If i have a DHCP Server above two routers and a cleint computer below and the client computer is connected to a router with DHCP Relay, will dhcp pass through those two routers?

Here is an example

```
Internet
   |
   |
 Router 0 (DHCP Server)
   |
   |
 Router 1
   |
   |
 Router 2
   |
   |
 Router with DHCP Relay pointing to Router 0
   |
   |
Client PC
```

Would the Client PC get DHCP relay from the Router 0? Or do i need to enable dhcp relay on all the routers?

Comment: I haven't seen this type of setup before, but seeing that the DHCP Relay router will send the DHCP packets as Unicast to Router 0 I'm thinking it should work.

Comment: The DHCP Relay router should be sufficient. It will send the DHCP client broadcast packet as a unicast packet to Router 0. Routers 1 and 2 will forward/route this as a unicast packet. They do not need to "relay" the clients DHCP broadcast.

Comment: And apologies to @joeqwerty for essentially stealing this one.  If you create an answer, I'll delete mine. :)

Comment: @TheCleaner: No worries. You take this one.

Comment: As an aside, I mocked this up in Cisco Packet Tracer and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the routing is in place such that the DHCP relay to Router 0 actually traverses Router 2 & 1 to Router 0 and back, then yes, it will work just fine.  It's no different than VLANs across Layer 3 switches with IP Forwarding enabled.  You could even think of it as getting a DHCP address across a WAN link from a remote DHCP server if you'd like.